# Laravel - wkhtmltopdf on OS X returning an error

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using [Laravel Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) as a wrapper for `WKHTMLToPDF`, to allow my app to generate PDFs. Unfortunately, I am receiving this error:

```
The exit status code '126' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /audit/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: 
cannot execute binary file
"
stdout: ""
command: /audit/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality
```

I installed both 64 bit packages (PDF and Image) through `Composer`, following these instructions: https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#wkhtmltopdf-binary-as-composer-dependencies, and I can see the packages have installed within the /vendor/ folder of my app.

If I `cd` into the PDF directory and run `sh ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64`, it returns: `cannot execute binary file`.

Previously, I have run these two commands on the folder to try and stop this error: `chmod a+x wkhtmltopdf-amd64` and `sudo chmod +x wkhtmltopdf-amd64` - but neither appear to have resolved this issue of executing a binary file.

I am on the latest version of OS X, any help or guidance as to how I can get this working would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm just now getting set up with the same configuration - MAMP, OSX, Laravel, Snappy.

I found that I had to download the OSX binary from here and install it:
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Once installed, the wkhtmltopdf binary will be in `/usr/local/bin`

Once installed, be sure you can run the command from Terminal.

Then, in your `config/snappy.php` file, be sure the 'binary' option is set to the proper path.

After this, mine works fine.

Answer (score 2):

first of all go to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html , then download the proper package according to your os . after installing the package do the followings :

in the config/snappy.php file , write the name of the {bin file} which has been installed in /usr/local/bin , which in my case is wkhtmltopdf :

'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/{bin file}'

so :

'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

I had installed wkhtmltopdf on my Catalina Edition using the dmg installer file. So the "wkhtmltopdf" command works in the terminal. So all I had to do was instead of giving a path in the snappy.php, I simply passed the command name - "wkhtmltopdf".

So my snappy config looks like this:

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => 'wkhtmltopdf',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [
        'enable-local-file-access' => true,
        'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
    ],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

And now this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Homestead? I think some of the binary dependencies are Linux-based and won't work if installed on a Mac. I think!

Comment: I'm using MAMP actually.

Comment: Almost certainly the problem. https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/99 may help.

Comment: I installed the Mac binaries though - http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html. Maybe I need further configuration now that it's installed? I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install the correct package according to your system here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
2. Make sure the binaries are loaded in '/usr/local/bin' directory.
3. Update your project .env by adding new entry as:
   WKHTML_PDF_BINARY='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
4. Make sure the correct binary path is obtained from the project .env file.

*You should be able to generate PDF files now.*

System:

- macOS Big Sur
- PHP 7.4
- Composer 2
- wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6